# No suitable cloud connector found Error in IntelliJ Vs Working in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Am having spring boot application, which is running fine in eclipse. But not in IntelliJ. With no setup differences between IDEs, eclipse is working fine with same code but not IntelliJ.

**IntelliJ:**

```
May 18, 2021 6:13:31 PM org.springframework.cloud.localconfig.PropertiesFileResolver findCloudPropertiesFileFromClasspath
WARNING: the properties file spring-cloud-bootstrap.properties contained properties besides spring.cloud.propertiesFile; ignoring
May 18, 2021 6:13:31 PM org.springframework.cloud.localconfig.PropertiesFileResolver findCloudPropertiesFileFromClasspath
INFO: derived configuration file name: src\test\resources\local-service-info.properties
May 18, 2021 6:13:31 PM org.springframework.cloud.localconfig.PropertiesFileResolver findCloudPropertiesFile
INFO: using configuration file derived from spring-cloud-bootstrap.properties
May 18, 2021 6:13:31 PM org.springframework.cloud.localconfig.LocalConfigConnector readFileProperties
INFO: properties file src\test\resources\local-service-info.properties does not exist; probably running in a real cloud
May 18, 2021 6:13:31 PM org.springframework.cloud.localconfig.LocalConfigConnector isInMatchingCloud
INFO: the property spring.cloud.appId was not found in the system properties or configuration file
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No suitable cloud connector found
    at org.springframework.cloud.CloudFactory.getCloud(CloudFactory.java:55)
    at com.comcast.xrm.video.vrs.collector.application.Application.main(Application.java:106)
```

I had seen other posts related to same error and tried few setups. But no luck.

My main class contains the code new CloudFactory().getCloud(); which was given as a solution to this problem

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why this is working differently in Eclipse and IntelliJ. It is likely due to differences in the run configuration and the ability to find the file `src\test\resources\local-service-info.properties`:

```
INFO: properties file src\test\resources\local-service-info.properties does not exist; probably running in a real cloud
```

You should be aware, however, that the Spring Cloud Connectors library is [in maintenance mode](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors#spring-cloud-connectors-), and its use is discouraged in favor of the newer [Java CFEnv](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv) library.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. It was an existing application. I don't have much control except get this running. Trying to run this in intelliJ and got stuck.